# jsf p:tree checkbox selection

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces, tree

**How can I select only a parent node (in a checkbox p:tree) without the children**? By default the children are also selected, what I want to avoid. So the problem is, that I can't select a parent node without selecting the children too.

Is there a solution? maybe with a  method?

thanks!

here is my code:

```
<h:form id="selectCategoryForm">
    <p:tree id="categoryTree" value="#{bean.categories}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{bean.selectedCategories}" >
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.path}" escape="false"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `propagateSelectionDown="false"` on your treetable to disable the selection propagation down the tree

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<h:form id="selectCategoryForm">
    <p:tree id="categoryTree" value="#{bean.categories}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{bean.selectedCategories}" >
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{bean.onNodeSelect}" update="@this"/>
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.path}" escape="false"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

and on the bean:

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    TreeNode treeNode = event.getTreeNode();
    TreeNode parentTreeNode = treeNode.getParent();
    parentTreeNode.setSelected(true);
}
```